# JQuery: Text getting added to textbox for some reason that I can't figure out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a noob with JQuery, most of the fiddle you see below is what I have put together from many sources on SO or got help with:
http://jsfiddle.net/7wp9rs2s/3/

to get the same problem that I am getting follow these steps:
Double click on "asd" on the right, click out of there so it gets back to being a text,
repeat the above step
you should now see the text getting added to the old text
(It's harder to explain it but once you see it you will know what I am talking about)

I think my problem has something to with this:

```
$("#tempData").data("data", text);
```

as thats where I am saving the input's value temporarily... but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Strangely, clicking on "..." instead of "asd" does not produce the same problem...

Comment: You are adding a new span inside the older span on blur, you surely want instead: `$this.prev().text(value == "" ? '...' : value).show();` See: http://jsfiddle.net/7wp9rs2s/7/

Comment: `$this.find('span')` is returning multple spans, both the outer and inner ones. Then `.text()` concatenates the text of each of them.

Comment: Why do you think `.data()` has anything to do with it? `data()` doesn't modify what any other functions return.

Comment: Still learning jQuery...

Comment: @A.Wolff, clicking on the dots now gives another problem... also guys, please post your answers as answers below so I can select your answer if it works as well as comment/reply to you easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a better way to do what you want to do, with html5 and good practices of CSS:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
   <input type="text" class="input"/>
   <span class="output">...</span><br>
   <input type="text" class="input"/>
   <span class="output">...</span><br>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.content>input{
  display: none; /*apply a none displayed default status*/
}
.content>span{
  cursor: pointer;/* change the mouse to pointer in order to create the click*/
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {//this is a auto-executing anonymous javaScript function
  var showText = function () {
    $(this).hide();//show text
    $(this.nextElementSibling).show();//hide input
  };


$('.input').on('input', function () {// in case someone press any key to an input
  this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML =  this.value;// will apply those changes to next sibling in this case will be span element
});
$('.output').on('dblclick', function () {//in clase someone double click the output
  $(this).hide(); //it hides the output
  $(this.previousElementSibling).show();//and show the previous sibling  in this case will be input tag
});
$('.input').blur(showText).keypress(function (e) {//in case the input is unfucused or keypress
    if(e.which === 13) { //in case enter key is pressed
      showText.call(this);//execute de showText function and send the current context
    }
});
});
```

http://jsbin.com/nekicewicu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I'm not used to using HTML 5... not sure whats the difference, if it will go with with my regular code and a bit scared how I will handle it if things go wrong :(

Comment: I do like how elegant/clean your code looks though, can you please comment each part so that I can know whats going on and I'll try to get it working with what I already have, if it works I'll pick your answer (already upvoted!) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it must have been a cache issue :) Thanks for your help!